# Как правильно произнести дату?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-варианта, периоды-времени

Как правильно произносить: ***третьего ноль пятого*** тысяча девятьсот двадцатого или ***третьего мая*** тысяча девятьсот двадцатого?

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу здесь несколько возможностей оформления и, соответственно, произношения — всё зависит от ситуации (к сожалению, вы её не "обозначили").

1. Возможный диалог, в котором один человек не успел записать дату, другой — еще раз ее четко произносит.

*— Когда-когда?

— Повторяю, записывай. **Третьего. Пятого.** [Тысяча девятьсот] **Двадцатого.***

2. При заполнении анкет, бланков или заявлений, в которых и для числа, и для месяца отведены две позиции (допустим, дата рождения или получения гражданства):

**ноль три, ноль пять, тысяча девятьсот двадцать;

ноль третьего ноль пятого тысяча девятьсот двадцатого.**

3. Обычная (стандартная) ситуация: вопрос — ответ.

*— Ты помнишь, когда родилась твоя бабушка?

— Конечно! **Третьего мая тысяча девятьсот двадцатого** [года].*

Answer (score 0):

Оба правильно: если первое произносится для записи, то есть диктуете, как правильно записать, то вполне годно.